# How to update a row value of one table by add mulitple row values of one table?

Tags: mysql

I have a sales table and a order table.

In sales table multiple rows having same order id.

What i need to update the order table amount by adding the amounts of sales table? 
where order table id match with sales table order id?

sales table

```
ID   |   amount    |  order_id  |
----------------------------
 1   |       100 |  1 |
 2   |       100 |  1 |
 3   |       300 |  2 |
 4   |       500 |  2 |
```

order table

```
ID   |   amount    
---------------------
 1   |       0.00 
 2   |       0.00
```

Result on order:

```
    ID   |   amount    
    ---------------------
     1   |       200.00 
     2   |       800.00
```

Comment: show your table structure, some example data and an expected output please-

Comment: thanks @lolka_bolka for reply. I have updated my question as per suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `update` with a `join` and a subquery:

```
update orders o
join (select order_id, sum(amount) amount 
      from sales 
      group by order_id) s on o.id = s.order_id
set o.amount = s.amount
```

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes. Save my day. +1 once having reputation.

Answer (score 1):

If the process will be executed just once you can archieve it doing a TRUNCATE and INSERT all the data.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE order;
INSERT INTO order SELECT order_id, SUM(amount) FROM sales GROUP BY order_id;
```

If you must keep the records in order, you can update the values with the new computed data, doing the solution from sgeddes.

```
UPDATE orders o
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, SUM(amount) amount 
      FROM sales 
      GROUP BY order_id) s ON o.id = s.order_id
SET o.amount = s.amount
```

If you want to keep the updates during the time, you could create a TRIGGER to be executed every time a record is inserted into sales to update orders.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER order_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON sales
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   -- HERE UPDATE/INSERT VALUES INTO ORDERS.

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```